# Как перечитать конфиг nginx с помощью systemd?

Tags: nginx, systemd

```
запуск systemctl start nginx
останов systemctl stop nginx
перезапуск systemctl restart nginx
перечитать конфиг systemctl ? nginx
```

Comment: systemctl reload nginx

Answer (score 0):

Возможно
systemctl reload?

Это загрузка новой кофигурации без презапуска самого сервера.

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

или возможно

```
systemctl reload nginx.service
```